# Ambiguous redirect when redirecting to multiple files using Bash

Tags: bash, redirect, pipe

```
$ echo "" >  /home/jem/rep_0[1-3]/logs/SystemOut.log
bash: /home/jem/rep_0[1-3]/logs/SystemOut.log: ambiguous redirect
```

Can I redirect to multiple files at a time?

Edit: Any answer that allows use of the ambiguous file reference?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That's what tee is for:

```
command | tee file1 file2 file3 > file4
```

tee also outputs to stdout, so you may want either to put one file after a redirect (as shown above), or send stdout to `/dev/null`.

For your case:

```
echo "" | tee /home/jem/rep_0[1-3]/logs/SystemOut.log >/dev/null
```

Comment: also very useful on embedded, f.e. to turn off all leds on a router `echo none|tee /sys/class/leds/*/trigger; echo 0|tee /sys/class/leds/*/brightness`

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using [`tee`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29), which reads from stdin and writes to stdout and files. Since `tee` also outputs to stdout, I've chosen to direct it's output to `/dev/null`. Note that bash expansion matches against the existing files, so the files you're trying to write to must exist before executing this command for it to work.

```
$ echo "" | tee /home/jem/rep_0[1-3]/logs/SystemOut.log > /dev/null
```

As a side note, the `""` you pass to `echo` is redundant.

Not directly relevant to your question, but if you don't rely on bash expansion you can have multiple pipes.

```
$ echo hello > foo > bar > baz
$ cat foo bar baz
hello
hello
hello
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this same question and just wanted to add the example with the wildcard since it hadn't been shown.  I think this is what you were looking for:

```
echo "" | tee *.log
```

Comment: exactly what I need, perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
echo "" | tee /home/jem/rep_0{1..3}/logs/SystemOut.log
```

To suppress the output to stdout, add this to the end of the commands above:

```
> /dev/null
```

The `echo` command in your question (which doesn't require the empty quotes) simply puts a newline in the files. If you want to create empty files, use the `touch` command.

Comment: Not just puts, overwrites contents with a newline.

Answer (score 0):

No. What about using `tee` twice?

```
echo "Your text" | tee file1 | tee file2 > file3
```

Comment: Thanks. I neglected to specify that I wanted to use the wildcard file reference.

Comment: You can specify multiple arguments to `tee`. You don't need to run it twice.

Comment: @Dennis - didn't know that. Learn something new every day!

Answer (score 0):

Pipe to the "tee" command to branch to a file and std out, the cascade the tee commands

Comment: Thanks. I neglected to specify that I wanted to use the wildcard file reference.

Comment: You can specify multiple arguments to `tee` instead of cascading them.