# How to put text in multiple files using command ECHO?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

How to put text in multiple files using command `echo`?

I want to put same text in multiple files, but this command works on only one file:

```
echo "my text" > myfile.php
```

But I want a working command line for something like this:

```
echo "my text" > myfile.php,myfile.txt,myfile,myfile.html
```

How can I put text in multiple files or custom extension files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ambiguous redirect when redirecting to multiple files using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4505339/608639), [Redirecting stdout/stderr to multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8124220/608639), [Append same text to many files using cat or echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50089), etc.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [tee](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html) command copies what it reads from standard input to one or more files, and also writes the data to its standard output. So you can use:

```
echo my text | tee file1 file2 file3 > /dev/null
```

or maybe:

```
echo my text | tee file1 file2 > file3
```

Comment: -/bin/sh: tee: not found

Answer (score 11):

echo your text | tee -a f1 f2 f3

-a for Append to the given FILEs. Do not overwrite.
-I for Ignore interrupt signals.

Answer (score 1):

In a parallel universe you might have done:

```
(echo myfile.php; echo myfile.txt; echo myfile; echo myfile.html; echo /dev/stdout) |\
 parallel 'echo "hello other world" >| {}'
```

This using GNU parallel (https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel).

Comment: That is really ugly! Why start an unnecessary background process and then run 5 separate `echo` commands? `parallel ... ::: fileA fileB fileC`